# Compatibility between jquery and google ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing a page for supporting to both desktop and mobile version. It seems there is some problem to the compatibility between jquery and google ajax. I have three multipage within a page and I declare the three javascript in different order and javascript can work for specific page, but none of the order can serve for all. Do anyone have similar experience in using all libraries together?

**When declare the javascript as below**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

an error Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'isNumeric' for below script

```
var from = ($.isNumeric(fromArray[2]) ? '+'+fromArray[2] : ((fromArray[2]=='sysid') ? '98765432' : fromArray[2]));
```

---

**When declare the javascript as below**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

an another error Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'isPlainObject' for below script in **jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js**

```
deferred.resolve( name, reverse, $to, $from, true );
```

---

**When declare the javascript as below**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

> ```
> error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u for below script 
>
>     $obj = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.response);
>
> ---
>
> &lt;div data-role="page" id="page1"&gt;
>
> &lt;div data-role="page" id="sendpage"  data-add-back-btn="true"&gt;
>
> ..
> var from = ($.isNumeric(fromArray[2]) ? '+'+fromArray[2] : ((fromArray[2]=='sysid') ? '98765432' : fromArray[2]));
> ..
>
> &lt;div data-role="page" id="createcamppage" data-add-back-btn="true"&gt;
>
> ..
> $obj = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.response);
> ..
> ```

Comment: Why would you want to load more than one jquery version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading `2-jquery versions` use the latest instead of `older jquery versions`

Try this,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

There is nothing for `compatibility` between `jquery` and `google ajax` both are [CDN's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and [jquery CDN](http://jquery.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

You are including jquery twice in your file. Remove the third script include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since its same as your first script include but from different CDN. Both provide you same library (jquery).

Though your last include is of version 1.3.2, which might be cause for errors coming up. Just remove last include and it should work good.

Comment: When remove the jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js, then all the form formatting will be lost.

Comment: Corrected file name to exclude.